# Overriding method as the field in Scala

Tags: scala

I don't understand. Why does Scala support override method as field:

```
abstract class A {
    def i: Int;
}

class B extends A {
    val i = 123;
}

val obj:A = new B();

println(obj.i)
```

Method `i` is as field `i`. Why?

Comment: Because val is a ... method (in internal representation). And val is looks like a method because of [Uniform Access Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle).

Comment: Uniform Access Principle, but in Scala you might leave out empty parentheses for method, same affect

Comment: I mean method with `def`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One quick way to see what's going on here is to compile this code and use `javap` to inspect the resulting classes. Here we get the following for `A`:

```
public abstract class A implements scala.ScalaObject {
  public abstract int i();
  public A();
}
```

And for `B` (with `-p`, so we see any private members):

```
public class B extends A implements scala.ScalaObject {
  private final int i;
  public int i();
  public B();
}
```

So the `val` just ends up as a private field with a getter—much like what you'd write in idiomatic Java, although the naming convention is different (and isn't really a *convention*, since the compiler handles it for you).

Answer (score 4):

Travis' answer explains *how*, at the implementation level, some methods can be overridden by a field in Scala but not *why*. The answer to the *why* question is related to two programming language design principles: the [Uniform Access Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle) and the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

The **Uniform Access Principle** essentially says that callers shouldn't have to distinguish between reading a property through a method and reading it through a field -- both calls should look the same and should not betray whether they involve storage or computation.

The **Liskov Substitution Principle** essentially says that a subtype must honor all the contracts of its parent type. A subtype *is* allowed to honor stronger contracts than its parent type, but it *must not* violate any of its parent's contracts.

In Scala, declaring a `def` without a parameter list implies a certain contract. Namely, it implies that accessing the associated property will return a value of the declared type. Since referential transparency *is not* guaranteed, subsequent accesses may or may not return the same value.

Clearly, a `val` satisfies the same contract. However, a `val` makes an even stronger guarantee: every access will result in the same value. Since this is a *stronger* contract, it's perfectly consistent with the Liskov Substitution Principle for a subtype to use a `val` to implement a `def`. Along the same lines, it's prohibited for a subtype to use a `def` to implement a `val`.